# Visual studio 2012 my custom add in won't load on startup

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-addins

I have a custom add in working fine to measure compile time and do some other custom stuff.

The problem is that every day I have to manually go to

Tools -> Add-in Manager

and enable my custom add in.

Comment: Was this originally a VS2010 add-in that you've migrated to VS2012?

Comment: No no , I've created a VS2012 Add in